how to pipe output of find into eog
I'm trying to view photos in a slideshow which are nested within other folders but can be found with the find command.
The find command on its own does find all the listed photos but this -
find  /path/to/parent/folder -name "*2006*" | eog --slide-show

Does not display the slideshow I had hoped for. Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

I don't use eog but if it doesn't accept arguments from stdin use xargs eog but remember to use with -0 option with both find and xargs.

Thanks, you might be onto something https://www.howtogeek.com/435164/how-to-use-the-xargs-command-on-linux/  Need to string some Linux commands together, but one of them doesn't accept piped input? xargs is the command for you.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk what is the -0 option?

it's explained in man xargs and man find. Basically you need to use it to correctly handle filenames with whitespaces and other characters.

sorry, in find it's -print0

You could use the -exec flag of find:
For a slideshow:
This opens all images that are matching *2006* and additionaly all images in directories matching *2006* and there might be duplicates. As you said you can only show matching files with -type f or only show files in matching directories with -type d.
find  /path/to/parent/folder -name "*2006*" -exec eog --slide-show {} +
This would open every found image in a new eog instance and a slideshow for every found directory:
find  /path/to/parent/folder -name "*2006*" -exec eog --slide-show {} \;

This would show one photo at a time. With {} + in place of {} \;, it would show a batch of images, but it's not guaranteed to be all found files in one go (there might be more than one invocation of the utility needed).  I'm unfamiliar with eog, but if it had a way of reading the pathnames from some file or stream, then that may be a better option.

@Kusalananda why would it not be all found files in one go? Does it have a limit of a certain mumber or something.. I don't mind pushing the arrow key to move forward..

@cardamom The solution using {} \; would execute eog for a found file. Then wait for it to exit. Then do the same thing for the next file.

This would work as expected if find was only finding a single folder. It's unclear if the find command in the question is supposed to find files or directories or a mix of both.

@ctx Thanks and good you fixed that with the plus sign as per the suggestion in the comments. Okay you even explained what I observed as strange behaviour, that it was opening a new eog instance with each command. Yes, @Kusalananda even before you posted that I was noticing other bad behaviour of the command and realised it was because eog was trying to open the directories that find found. That was fixed by adding a  type -f to the find part of the command.
